# where are startup apps formerly found in system settings?

Tags: macos, user-account, ventura

Formerly I could add or remove apps autostarted at user login in the System Settings/Users & Groups  page... but they don't appear there any more.  I couldn't find them in the other several System Settings screens I checked.  Can someone tell me where to control a user's login autostart apps now?  Running MacOs Ventura 13.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In is in System Settings.
Choose General and then on the screen is Login Items.

Found by typing Login into the Systems Settings search.

System Settings is not as well structured as in previous OSX and you need to use search a lot.

In the terminal textual output od all the login items can be found by `sudo sfltool dumpbtm`
sfltool man page is outdated best information seems to be [Apple documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/deployment/depdca572563/web)

Comment: The fact that I didn't read carefully :)

Comment: Leaving this here, may be useful if you're looking for a way to list the startup items via Terminal: https://github.com/luckman212/login-items-dump